# Character vs story

Tags: creative-writing, characters, screenwriting, story

How much should I allow my characters to influence my plotting, and how much should the plot influence how I create my characters? Should I begin with a plot and then devise my characters to be "right" for it, or should I devise my characters, and then devise a plot that would be "right" for that cast of characters?

Comment: I would say that it depends on the type of story. A formulaic thriller could be plot-driven, with characters created to fit certain necessary roles. A more literary work might be character-driven; the author devises the characters and sees where their interactions take the story.

Comment: **IT DEPENDS.** This question is way too broad, and forces an extreme amount of writing work to fill in all the gaps – don't expect that kind of answer every time.

Comment: They are both an integral part of a story. Your question is a bit like asking which came first of the hen and the egg. To get an idea of how you can do it, check out [the Snowflake Method](https://www.advancedfictionwriting.com/articles/snowflake-method/).

Answer (score 0):

A big theme in my writing is based on a quote that "Character is what you are in the dark" and sets up scenarios that will leave the only witnesses to my characters actions to be the audience.

The specifics will change, but typically the scenario boils down to a moment where my character is given choice.  They can obtain their goals... but they have to compromise their morals.  But there will be no one to witness this compromise.  No one to call them out.   All they have to do is betray their core belief, and they get what they want.  And no one will ever know... except them.

That said, it would seem like the character informs the story... but that simply isn't the case.  Often times these moments simply make themselves known to me while I'm fleshing out plot.  Again, it's a core theme in my writing, so I'm quick to pick out the opportunity.

And with that said, I have killed writing projects... or at least put them on the backburner because I have wonderful characters, but no story which feels right for them as equally as I have killed writing projects for having a rich story... but no characters to put through it (in the latter case, it's usually I have an amazing setting but can't quite fall in love with the characters enough to find some who I want to see explore it).  And it's not as simple as taking the orphan characters and shoving them into the abandoned set.  Some settings are not right for some characters and vice versa.

To put it in the best way I can, you are asking "Which Came First: The Chicken or Egg" question.   But it's the wrong question.  What you should be asking yourself is "If I want to make the perfect Breakfast, which do I cook first:  The Bacon or the Eggs?"

Because the answer to that question is the same as the other: "I don't care, so long as neither is burnt when you're done."